# .N in data.table with conditions

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

I am trying to count multiple .N for data.table with conditions

I have a data.table

```
SD = data.table(x=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), y=c("a", "a", "b", "b","a", "a",
                 "b", "b"), z= c("x", "x", "y","y", "x","z","x","w"))
```

I want to count two things:

1. counts of each combination by x and y

I did it this way

```
SD[,.N, .(x,y)]
```

and output is what I want

```
   x y N
1: 1 a 2 
2: 1 b 2 
3: 2 a 2 
4: 2 b 2
```

2. counts of each combination by x and y where z == "x"

As a quick solution I did

```
SD[z == "x", .N, .(x,y)]

merge.data.table(SD[,.N, .(x,y)],
                 SD[z == "x", .N, .(x,y)], 
                 by = c('x','y'), all.x =TRUE)`
```

Is there any way to do both in one line of code without joins?
It works but takes a long time due to the big size of data.table

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one:

```
SD[, .(.N, count2 = sum(z == 'x')), .(x,y)]
#    x y N count2
# 1: 1 a 2      2
# 2: 1 b 2      0
# 3: 2 a 2      1
# 4: 2 b 2      1
```

In addition to counting the number of rows by unique x-y combination, we also count the number of rows where `z == 'x'` in each x-y combination.